# How to avoid deprecation warnings for GWT HorizontalSplitPanel in NetBeans Java project?

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans, deprecated

Is it possible to avoid deprecation warning while compiling code with utility methods like:

```
public static void doSthForHorizontalSplitPanel(HorizontalSplitPanel hsp) {...}
```

and explicit declaration and/or creation of HorizontalSplitPanel widget, e.g.:

```
protected HorizontalSplitPanel main;
...
    main  = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
```

**My goal is to eliminate these warnings** without removing `HorizontalSplitPanel` usage, not giving global compiler flag (`-Xlint:-deprecation`) and **with aid of minimal manual refactoring** in terms of possible impact on code using HorizontalSplitPanel and my utility methods (i.e. as little code changes as possible).

Annotation `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` at method or class level seems not to work because of `import HorizontalSplitPanel` statements, replacement of deprecated HorizontalSplitPanel class in not an option (for now).

**Is my goal possible to achieve at all? If so, what would be the best approach?**

*I'm using NetBeans 7.1, Java 1.6, GWT 2.3.*

Answer (score 3):

Standards mode and SplitlayoutPanel works better than the deprecated HorizontalSplitPanel.
Try this code you have to replace with HorizontalSplitPanel with HorizontalSplitLayoutPanel.
This code actually uses latest SplitLayoutPanel and the methods are equivalent to Deprecated HorizontalSplitPanel. The advantage is you don't have to change the code. Also pasted code for VerticalSplitPanel alternative VerticalSplitLayoutPanel. VerticalSplitLayoutPanel is unit tested and works fine.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SplitLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

/**
 * author: MKK
 * Date: 4/29/13
 * Time: 10:41 AM
 * /**
 *
 * GWT depecrated HorizontalSplitpanel as of version 2.0.
 * This is a wrapper class which extends new SplitLayoutPanel and has all the methods of deprecated old Splitpanels for
 * seamless integration with existing code without breaking.
 * Replacement of old HorizontalSplitLayoutPanel with new SplitLayoutPanel
 * 
 *
 */
public class HorizontalSplitLayoutPanel extends SplitLayoutPanel{


    private ScrollPanel leftScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
    private ScrollPanel rightScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
    private Widget leftWidget;
    private Widget rightWidget;


    public HorizontalSplitLayoutPanel(){
        super();
        init();

    }
    boolean dragged;
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
            case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN:
                dragged = true;
                break;
            case Event.ONMOUSEUP:
                dragged = false;
                break;
            case Event.ONMOUSEMOVE:
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean isResizing(){
        return dragged;
    }

    private void init() {
        setSize("100%", "100%");
        addWest(leftScrollPanel, 300);
        add(rightScrollPanel);
        sinkEvents(Event.ONMOUSEDOWN | Event.ONMOUSEUP );
    }

    public HorizontalSplitLayoutPanel(int splitterSize) {
        super(splitterSize);
        init();
    }


    public void setLeftWidget(Widget widget){
        this.leftWidget = widget;
        leftScrollPanel.clear();
        leftScrollPanel.add(widget);
        setSplitPosition("30%");
        setWidgetToggleDisplayAllowed(leftScrollPanel,true);
    }

    public void setRightWidget(Widget widget){
        try {
            this.rightWidget = widget;
            rightScrollPanel.clear();
            rightScrollPanel.add(widget);
            setSplitPosition("30%");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }


    public void removeWidget(Widget widget){
        try {
            if( leftScrollPanel.getWidget()== widget){
                leftScrollPanel.remove(widget);
                return;
            }
            rightScrollPanel.remove(widget);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }


    public void setSplitPosition(String percent){
        if( percent.toLowerCase().indexOf("px") > -1){
            percent = percent.replace("px","").trim();
            int p = Integer.parseInt(percent);
            setSplitPosition(p);
            return;
        }
        percent = percent.replace("%","").trim();
        int p = Integer.parseInt(percent);
        double size =  (getOffsetWidth()*p)/100.0;
        if( p < 1.0 ){
           size = 600;
        }
        setWidgetSize(leftScrollPanel, size);
    }

    public void setSplitPosition(int pixels){
        setWidgetSize(leftScrollPanel, pixels);

    }


    public void hideLeftWidget() {
        leftScrollPanel.clear();
        setWidgetMinSize(leftScrollPanel,0);
    }

    public void showLeftWidget(){
        leftScrollPanel.add(leftWidget);
    }
    public void hideRightWidget() {
        rightScrollPanel.clear();
        setWidgetMinSize(rightScrollPanel,0);
    }

    public void showRightWidget(){
        rightScrollPanel.add(rightWidget);
    }
}

import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SplitLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

/**
 *
 * GWT depecrated VerticalSplitPanel as of version 2.0.
 * This is a wrapper class which extends new SplitLayoutPanel and has all the methods of deprecated old Splitpanels for
 * seamless integration with existing code without breaking.
 * Replacement of old VerticalSplitPanel with new SplitLayoutPanel
 * 
 *
 */
public class VerticalSplitLayoutPanel extends SplitLayoutPanel {

    private Widget topWidget;
    private Widget bottomWidget;
    private int offset=100;

    private ScrollPanel topScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
    private ScrollPanel bottomScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();




    public VerticalSplitLayoutPanel() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public VerticalSplitLayoutPanel(int splitterSize) {
        super(splitterSize);
        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        setSize("100%", "100%");
        //int clientH = Window.getClientHeight()-offset;
        // double size = clientH * 50/100;
        addNorth(topScrollPanel, getOffsetHeight()/2.0);
        add(bottomScrollPanel);

        sinkEvents(Event.ONMOUSEDOWN | Event.ONMOUSEUP );
    }

    boolean dragged;
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
            case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN:
                dragged = true;
                break;
            case Event.ONMOUSEUP:
                dragged = false;
                break;
            case Event.ONMOUSEMOVE:
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean isResizing(){
        return dragged;
    }

    public void setTopWidget(Widget widget){
        topScrollPanel.add(widget);
    }

    public void setBottomWidget(Widget widget){
        bottomScrollPanel.add(widget);
    }


    public void removeWidget(Widget widget){
        try {
            if( topScrollPanel.getWidget()== widget){
                topScrollPanel.remove(widget);
                return;
            }
            bottomScrollPanel.remove(widget);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }


    public void setSplitPosition(String percent){
        if( percent.toLowerCase().indexOf("px") > -1){
            percent = percent.replace("px","").trim();
            int p = Integer.parseInt(percent);
            setSplitPosition(p);
            return;
        }
        percent = percent.replace("%","").trim();
        int p = Integer.parseInt(percent);
        int oH =  getOffsetHeight();
        if( oH == 0 ){
            oH = (Window.getClientHeight()-offset);
        }
        double h = (oH*p)/100.0;
        setWidgetSize(topScrollPanel, h);

    }


    public void setSplitPosition(int pixels){
        setWidgetSize(topScrollPanel, pixels);

    }



    public void setOffset(int size){
        this.offset = size;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**My approach is as follows.**

Replace every usage of `HorizontalSplitPanel` with `HorizontalSplitPanelWrapper` defined below, then fix imports - this will eliminate `import HorizontalSplitPanel` and add `import HorizontalSplitPanelWrapper`. Done.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HorizontalSplitPanelWrapper implements IsWidget {

    private Panel hsp = new com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel();

    public Widget asWidget() {
        return hsp;
    }

    public com.google.gwt.user.client.Element getElement() {
        return hsp.getElement();
    }

    public <H extends EventHandler> HandlerRegistration addHandler(final H handler, GwtEvent.Type<H> type) {
        return hsp.addHandler(handler, type);
    }

    public boolean isResizing() {
        return ((com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel) hsp).isResizing();
    }

    public void setWidth(String width) {
        hsp.setWidth(width);
    }

    public void setSplitPosition(String pos) {
        ((com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel) hsp).setSplitPosition(pos);
    }

    public void add(IsWidget w) {
        hsp.add(w);
    }
}
```

**Additional remarks.**

My solution uses little trick with `IsWidget` interface from GWT - this minimizes code impact, because `Widget` can be substituted with implementation of `IsWidget` in most calls to GTW APIs.

Every method of `HorizontalSplitPanel` used in my code is now implemented by `HorizontalSplitPanelWrapper` and just delegated to internal HorizontalSplitPanel stored by `hsp` field.

There must be no declarations of fields and methods with HorizontalSplitPanel as type/param/result, as it will always yield deprecation warnings, regardless of `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`. Because of this, `hsp` field is declared as `Panel`.

If there are more methods of HorizontalSplitPanel used in rest of the code, there must be dummy delegator method in `HorizontalSplitPanelWrapper` for every one of them. Proper HorizontalSplitPanel object must be retrieved from field `hsp` with explicit cast in every such method.

**That's it.** No more deprecation warnings because of HorizontalSplitPanel, which still can be used.